# Python not able to make package after creating init file in directory and add adding sys.path.append

Tags: python, filesystems, sys

hi my directory structure is

```
app_data\
   __init__
   new.py
   variable.py
   folder\
      __init__
      new2.py
      new3.py
```

I want to import new module from new3.py file. The code of new3.py is below:

```
import sys
import os
#print sys.path
#print "-----------------------------" , __name__
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\Users\prince.dhadwal\Desktop\abc_data')
from abc_data import new
```

Also added the Path in env variable in windows machine.

Complete path of app_data folder is: `C:\Users\prince.dhadwal\Desktop\abc_data`
Path added in env variable:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\Perl\site\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\Tcl\8.5.17.0\bin;C:\Users\prince.dhadwal\Desktop\QATSS_PY;C:\Users\prince.dhadwal\Desktop\abc_data.
```

Below error is coming:

> ImportError: No module named abc_data

kindly help.